# How can I create a permanent drawer like interface in Scaffold without using the widget Drawer? Is it even possible?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want a drawer that does not closes, it needs to stay there permanently. I could do it with the help of a container, but I am confused in the process. Also how can I create the interface inside the drawer like (Featured,Bags and Shoes etc). Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Column` widget and generate your desired UI elements , and through `GestureDetector` you can navigate your pages on those respective elements.